# How to sort multiple array's array key descending with PHP

Tags: php

We have a multiple array like this:

```
Array
(
    [KAYSERİ EĞİTİM VE ARAŞTIRMA HASTANESİ] => Array
        (
            [MART 2014] => Array
                (
                    [41] => 1.418514098165
                )

            [ŞUBAT 2014] => Array
                (
                    [40] => 1.3457617248977
                )

            [OCAK 2014] => Array
                (
                    [39] => 1.32700992035769
                )

        )

)
```

I want to sort  key as descending  this array.Desired output will be like this:

```
Array
(
    [KAYSERİ EĞİTİM VE ARAŞTIRMA HASTANESİ] => Array
        (
            [OCAK 2014] => Array
                (
                    [39] => 1.32700992035769
                )


            [ŞUBAT 2014] => Array
                (
                    [40] => 1.3457617248977
                )

            [MART 2014] => Array
                (
                    [41] => 1.418514098165
                )



        )
)
```

Array key order should be ordered 39-40-41.

I tried this code but it doesnt work:

```
array_multisort($vakaArray,SORT_ASC);
```

How can we do this?

Thanks

Comment: Your data structure seems a little bit strange to me. If you want to sort by 39-40-41 shouldn't the months be inside? So: `array("39" => array("month" => "March", "value" => 1.xxxxx))`.

Comment: Is it does a matter? If it is we can change array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
array_multisort($vakaArray["KAYSERİ EĞİTİM VE ARAŞTIRMA HASTANESİ"],SORT_DESC);
```

To test it:

```
$vakaArray = array (
            "KAYSERİ EĞİTİM VE ARAŞTIRMA HASTANESİ" => array (
                    "MART 2014" => array (41 => 1.418514098165),
                    "ŞUBAT 2014" => array (40 => 1.3457617248977),
                    "OCAK 2014" => array (39 => 1.32700992035769)
            )
        );

array_multisort($vakaArray["KAYSERİ EĞİTİM VE ARAŞTIRMA HASTANESİ"], SORT_DESC);


echo "<pre>";
print_r($vakaArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [KAYSERİ EĞİTİM VE ARAŞTIRMA HASTANESİ] => Array
        (
            [OCAK 2014] => Array
                (
                    [39] => 1.3270099203577
                )

            [ŞUBAT 2014] => Array
                (
                    [40] => 1.3457617248977
                )

            [MART 2014] => Array
                (
                    [41] => 1.418514098165
                )

        )

)
```